# What is the order of output of the following piece of js code?

Tags: javascript, async-await

```js
async function async1() {
  console.log("a");
  await async2();
  console.log("b");
}

async function async2() {
  console.log("c");
  await async3();
  console.log("zzzzz");
}

const async3 = async () => {
  console.log("qqqq");
};

console.log("d");
async1();

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("e");
}, 0);

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log("f");
  resolve();
}).then(() => {
  console.log("g");
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Here's what I envisioned：
d, a, c, qqqq, f, zzzzz, b, g, e。

But the order in which it runs in the browser is：

```
d
a
c
qqqq
f
zzzzz
g
b
e
```

After the first execution completes, the microtask queue should be `console.log("zzzzz"); console.log("b"); console.log("g");`
The order of execution is, zzzzz b g, but the result in the browser is not like this, is there something I'm thinking wrong?

extremely grateful！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After the first execution completes, the microtask queue should be console.log("zzzzz"); console.log("b"); console.log("g");

"b" is not in the queue. The promise returned by `async2` has not yet resolved.

When synchronous code finishes, there are two promises in the resolved state: the one returned by `async3`, and the one created by `new Promise`. So the microtask queue contains 2 things: resuming `async2` (ie, `console.log("zzzzz")`) and the anonymous `.then` callback (ie, `console.log("g")`).

`async2` resumes, logs "zzzzz", then returns (which resolves its promise). A microtask is queued up to resume `async1` (ie, `console.log("b")`), but it must go to the end of the queue. Next the `.then` callback runs, logging "g". And only after that can `async1` resume and log "b".